# Is Poynting's theorem derived from Faraday & Lenz law?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy-conservation, electromagnetic-induction, poynting-vector, lenz-law

**Is Poynting's theorem dependent on Faraday & Lenz law?**

It's an eloquent equation that shows the electrical to mechanical conversion (and vice versa), but I assume that it heavily relies on the observations described in both Faraday's equation, and Lenz's statement. Otherwise, how can it be derived without those two assumptions?

Comment: Poynting's theorem is essentially conservation of energy for an electromagnetic field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faraday's and Lenz's law are part of what is know as Maxwell's equations. A set of differential equations that together with the Lorentz force law govern the classical behaviour of electric charges and electromagnetic fields.

The Poynting vector and Poynting theorem are a direct consequence of these laws.